# How to run javac with paths as argument that contain white spaces?

Tags: windows, javac

I am trying to run the following

```
javac -Xlint:unchecked -classpath C:/Users/a b/workspace/ @C:/Users/a b/workspace/files_to_compile
```

but I'm getting a

```
javac: invalid flag C:/users/a
```

I've also tried to surround both paths with double quotes but it doesn't seem to help a bit:

```
javac -Xlint:unchecked -classpath "C:/Users/a b/workspace/" @"C:/Users/a b/workspace/files_to_compile"
```

What am I doing wrong? This same code worked correctly in other computers (probably because they didn't have any white space in their paths..).

Thanks

Comment: Added the Windows tag because I think this is a Windows CLI issue, rather than a Java issue.

Comment: I just read a blog saying it is better to show how to solve the error than giving a solution. So: first try it with paths without spaces. Introduce quotes. Then classpath with blank, Then @ with blank. Quote before @. Try backslash.

Comment: It works fine for me with the double quotes.  What version of the Java SDK are you using?

Comment: "java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)"

Comment: Your second version with double quotes should work just fine. Can you post the contents of files_to_compile? Any paths listed in there that contain spaces will need to be quoted as well.

Comment: This is a trivial question. Try searching the internet for "how do I set the classpath"

Comment: So trivial that your own answer turned out to be useless. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've finally come up with the solution to the issue, and I guess no one here could have guessed it.

The cue to the answer lies with the fact that the contents of the files list (signaled as @ in the args) generally will have each one of its strings with the initial substring equal to what one passes as both the class path and the @ file.

so..

The trouble was never the command line parameters, as suggested, but with the contents of the @ file.

Each line of the file must be put in its own line, surrounded by quotes, and having into consideration that if you're in windows, you have to put the file names in the form of `C:\\a\\b\\c.txt`!!!

Answer (score 5):

Your second try is right

```
javac -Xlint:unchecked -classpath "C:/Users/a b/workspace/" @"C:/Users/a b/workspace/files_to_compile"
```

But to be complete, you have to escape the spaces into the text file "files_to_compile" by using:

- the same syntax as properties file : \

or

- double quote each line

I suggest the second but I'm not sure.

Comment: Almost there, it's weird but I only now saw this answer!

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit this was more difficult than I  had imagined.
After some trial and error I came up with the following:

C:\lol>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\javac" -cp "c:\lol\a b;c:\lol\foo bar" Lol.java

where the folder structure is like:

```
./foo bar
./foo bar/Moo.java
./Lol.java
./a b
./a b/AB.java
```

I made an archive with the folders and the java files, which you can grab at: 
http://www.pvv.ntnu.no/~rakhmato/tmp/lol.tar

You should ignore the @ option because it is enough to give the compiler one file and a proper class path, it can figure out where everything is on its own. Just give the compiler your Main.java and it will figure out what that file depends on.

I would also recommend you to write a .bat script of sorts to make things simpler. Nothing fancy, something like this:

compile.bat:

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\javac" -classpath "c:\lol\a b;c:\lol\foo bar" Main.java

..put that in your project folder and run compile.bat from CMD

Comment: "The caret symbol does directly answer my question so I'll accept your answer. **Unfortunately the SVN command doesn't seem to recognise it!**"

Comment: No one ever had a space in their folder before, certainly not anyone trying to compile a Java class.

Comment: I'm just stating the obvious: that the problem raised in your own first link remained unsolved, hence my concerns when you tell us that "This has already been answered." which of course may be said, though with the added adenda : "but not solved!"

Comment: "If you Are still having issues, try separating the paths with a colon." There's only a single path..

Comment: OK. what the hell is that @ doing in there? I thought you were using it to separate paths.

Comment: javac is your friend : "For a large number of source files, list the file names in a file, separated by blanks or line breaks. Then use the list file name on the javac command line, preceded by an @ character."

Comment: I'll try out what you're suggesting. I'm not sure I can leave the @ option off, there's no Main file (the files will form part of a library) so I have to have a list of files to compile.

Comment: You should consider spending some time to learn how to build with ant... You can make the @ option work by putting it in a path without spaces, because that's where I ran into trouble with it. I also think that the classpath has to be specified INSIDE that @file if you are going to use it. But really, look for instructions on building with ant. It's really straight forward and mostly automated.

Comment: I found the problem (I've put it as answer). Ant wouldn't help a bit here, I'm developing a kind of code generator, where I generate Java code and then need it to be compiled on the run.

Answer (score 2):

- First using the cd command in shell shift your directory to the one where your file is saved.

  ```
  cd /home/sayantani/PERSONAL\ FILES/sem\ 4\ courses/PLC/code/
  ```
- Note that I've used "\" whenever there is space involved. "PERSONAL FILES" becomes "PERSONAL\ FILES".
- Then use "javac filename.java"

  ```
  javac hello1.java
  ```

This should fix your problem.
Note that doing "javac" on the entire path from the default directory isn't working.(for me)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape spaces.

Put a `\` in front of each space and try that.

Comment: Annoyingly, backslashes won't escape on Windows; they're used for file paths

Answer (score 0):

Its taking only the 1st part of the Source String remove the space between `a b` from the path and it should work fine `C:/Users/a_b/workspace/" @"C:/Users/a_b/workspace/files_to_compile"` . Never you should have spaces in the path else the latter part will be ignored by the compiler or else you can put a '\' between `a\ b`

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a hack, but if you're on Windows 7 you can get around this using the `mklink` utility to create another folder pointing to the same place, but without spaces.

Edit: perhaps a better solution:

```
cd "C:/Users/a b/"
javac ... -classpath "Workspace" ...
```

Comment: This is to be a general purpose tool, I can't rely on that fact.

Comment: Does a `^` escape spaces? eg. `... -classpath "C:/Users/a^ b/workspace"`

Comment: :( is changing directory feasible?

Comment: I'll try that out later tonight. Doesn't seem terrible.

Answer (score 0):

From usage info for "java /?"

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin"

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin>java.exe
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
       (to execute a class)
or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
       (to execute a jar file)

where options include:
-client       to select the "client" VM
-server       to select the "server" VM
-hotspot      is a synonym for the "client" VM  [deprecated]
              The default VM is client.

-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
```

*-classpath* indicates that you need to use a semi-colon (";") for multiple paths.

Answer (score -1):

I can't test it but I'd suggest the following (as dmcgil suggested semicolon should be classpath separator on windows):

```
javac -Xlint:unchecked -classpath C:\Users\a^ b\workspace\;C:\Users\a^ b\workspace\files_to_compile
```

It seems that the [escape charachter for win shell is caret](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true).

That is also suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/279008/how-do-i-escape-spaces-in-command-line-in-windows-without-using-quotation-marks).

EDIT:

Also, in your question, I noticed usage of slashes (/) in paths, doesn't all versions of windows use backslashes(\) as file separators? I saw your comment somewhere on this thread stating just that, so I'll suppose you typoed in question.

Comment: The ^'s had been suggested in the past, and although it indeed works when doing cd's, it doesn't as javac parameter.