# Use batch to compile recursively with spaces in paths?

Tags: java, batch-file, javac

I currently have a batch script like so:

```
@echo off

dir /s /B *.java > sources.txt
javac -d bin @sources.txt

pause
```

This works in directories that don't have spaces in them, but now when they do.

I tried something like this to place all of the entries in quotes:

```
(for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /s /B *.java') do @echo "%%f") > sources.txt
```

But that just gave an error whenever `\` appeared in the path.  I need a way to escape all spaces as well as slashes and write it to `sources.txt`.

Comment: why not use gradle or maven or ant for this?

Comment: For the purpose of experimentation.

Comment: What is the point of experimentation about doing things the wrong way? There are many working solutions.

Comment: Experimentation is purely to see if I can do it.  If it works or can work, it is not wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(
  for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /s /B /A-D *.java') do (
    set "li=%%~f"
    set "li=!li: =^ !"
    set "li=!li:\=\\!"
    @echo "!li!"
  )
)>sources.txt
echo javac -d bin @sources.txt
endlocal
EXIT /B 0
```

according to [How to run javac with paths as argument that contain white spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934946/how-to-run-javac-with-paths-as-argument-that-contain-white-spaces)
you have to use unix path like `/` instead of `\`
so replacing  `set "li=!li:\=\\!"` by this `set "li=!li:\=/!"` should work too.

Comment: This works for me if I remove/comment-out the `set "li=!li: =^ !"` line. The caret is actually harmful, because it is read by javac as is, breaking the path/filename. Further, whitespaces in the files don't need to be escaped.